# How to create a machine user with access to project repo and keys repo for iOS build in CircleCI

Tags: ios, circleci, fastlane

I'm building an iOS app and uploading some artifacts using Fastlane (Scan and Gym).

It all looks good except I need to give my repositories in CircleCI a 'User Key' which has access to both my iOS repo and the certificates repo. My works organization is also linked to my account so I'd be giving permission for that too which is not ideal among other repos.

> It is best practice to create a machine user with access to just the project repo and the keys repo, and use that machine user to create a user key to reduce the level of GitHub access granted to the CircleCI project. - https://circleci.com/docs/ios-codesigning/

I read this as - "A literal second Github user who has access to the repos"

However, I'm not quite sure how to do that in CircleCI, because the only option I have for adding User Keys in project settings is to my main GitHub,

Can anyone please maybe share in a more detailed way how to achieve this?